# Making the bottom navigation bar not move when transitioning to new activity

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I have a bottom navigation bar on 3 activities and I have a few slide animations to transition between them. My problem is when the transition happens the navigation bar also moves. I'd like it to stay in place, how can I make that happen?

Here's the relevant part of my main/home activity. If needed of course I will include other parts of my project.

```
val navbar = findViewById<NavigationBarView>(R.id.bottom_navigation)

navbar.setOnItemSelectedListener { item ->
    when(item.itemId) {
        R.id.ic_settings -> {
            startActivity(Intent(this, SettingsActivity::class.java))
            overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_from_left, R.anim.slide_to_right)
            true
        }
        R.id.ic_stats -> {
            startActivity(Intent(this, StatsActivity::class.java))
            overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_from_right, R.anim.slide_to_left)
            true
        }
        else -> false
    }
}
```

Comment: Activity transitions affect the entire activity, including the navigation bar inside that activity. That's why frameworks like the [Navigation Component](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-getting-started) and Fragments only replace a portion of your UI, keeping your bottom navigation bar stationary. Why are you using multiple activities for this at all?

Comment: @ianhanniballake There are many reasons why a bottom navigation bar launches activities. One more obvious example is legacy use cases. Many older/perhaps large code bases use activity-based navigation, with each activity having various launch modes, deep linking etc. Migrating those to fragments isn't always straight forward.

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to be in the same place you need to go with Single Activity and Three fragments and add transition effects on the fragments.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**

I decided to try using shared element transition on the BottomNavigationView and it was pretty successful. Have a read at my Medium Article describing how to set this up: https://kelvinwatson.medium.com/bottomnavigationview-for-activity-based-app-navigation-using-shared-element-transition-c4de864d400f

TL:DR;

Essentially, you would start your activity with a shared element (the `BottomNavigationView` like so:

```
fun NavigationBarView.startActivityWithNavBarSharedTransition(
    activity:Activity,
    intent: Intent
) {
    val options = ActivityOptions.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(
        activity,
        this,
        activity.getString(R.string.nav_view_shared_element_transition_name)
    ).toBundle()
    activity.startActivity(intent, options)
}
```

I use the base class `NavigationBarView` here in case your app makes use of the `NavigationRailView`.

**PREVIOUS ANSWER**

As mentioned above, the "correct" way would be to use fragment-based navigation for bottom navigation in your app. However, for many legacy apps with complex activity-based navigation logic (with each activity having various launch modes, deep linking etc), refactoring these top level activities to fragments is not always feasible without significant rework.

I found [this article](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-implement-bottom-navigation-with-activities-in-android/) that makes use of `overridePendingTransition(0,0);`. I haven't tried this myself but it might help you. They even provided a video demo.

```
bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
  
        switch(item.getItemId())
        {
        case R.id.dashboard:
            startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),DashBoard.class));
            overridePendingTransition(0,0);
            return true;
        case R.id.home:
            return true;
        case R.id.about:
            startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),About.class));
            overridePendingTransition(0,0);
            return true;
         }
         return false;
     }
});
```

[image]